# Selecting items from MySQL table that are absent in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

Table: UserProfiles

```
+-----------+----------+
|         id| username |
+-----------+----------+
|          1| Carrera  |
|          2| Taylor   |
|          3| Diaz     |
+-----------+----------+
```

Table: Products

```
+-----------+----------+
|         id| name     |
+-----------+----------+
|        123| aaaaaaa  |
|        234| bbbbbbb  |
|        456| ccccccc  |
+-----------+----------+
```

Table: Purchase

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+
|         id| username | productid |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
|          1| Carrera  | 123       |
|          2| Taylor   | 234       |
|          3| Diaz     | 456       |
+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

How to select "Products" that user "Carrera" did not bought yet.

Answer (score 0):

As the title suggest, there's a `not in` operator you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   products
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT productid
                  FROM   purchase
                  WHERE  username = 'Carrera')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT P.id, P.name 
FROM Products P 
LEFT OUTER JOIN purchase P1 ON P.id = P1.productid AND P1.username = 'Carrera'
WHERE P1.id IS NULL;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT P.id, P.name
FROM Products P
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM purchase P1
                  WHERE P.id = P1.productid AND P1.username = 'Carrera');
```